# Kotlin: Using channel to make a simple work counter

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-coroutine-channel

I want to make a thread-safe counter to use on some of my services to count concurrent works.

Say, there's the http service that can serve multiple requests and has a property `isWorking` that is later to be used to display a spinner.

This is my implementation of the counter:

```
class CounterImpl @Inject constructor(
    @IoDispatcher private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    @MainDispatcher private val mainDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    private val log: Log
) : Counter {
    private val channel = Channel<Int>()
    private val _isWorking = MutableLiveData(false)
    override val isWorking = _isWorking.asFlow()

    init {
        MainScope().launch {
            channel.consumeAsFlow().onEach {
                log(FILE, "counter got a $it", LogType.Debug)
            }.scan(0) { acc, value -> acc + value }.map { it > 0}
                .collect {
                    withContext(mainDispatcher) {
                        _isWorking.value = it
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun invoke(increment: Boolean) {
        log(FILE, "counter invoked with $increment", LogType.Debug)
        channel.send(if (increment) 1 else -1)
    }
}
```

So the problem is that sometimes the last send call to the channel does not reach to the `consumeAsFlow` part of the code.

Here's a sample log of what happens:

```
[Debug] Counter: counter invoked with true
[Debug] Counter: counter invoked with false
[Debug] Counter: counter got a 1
```

Here, invoke is called once with `true` and there's a line that says `counter got a 1` that corresponds to that true (increment) call. But there's also an invocation with `false` and I would expect there to be a corresponding `counter got a 0` line. But that one never appears.

I also tried iterating the channel with `for c in channel` if that's what you're thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `Channel` to do that, a `MutableStateFlow` is enough because the operation you are doing (incrementing/decrementing a number) is free of side effects.

```
    val count = MutableStateFlow(0)

    fun update(increment: Boolean) {
        count.update { it + if (increment) 1 else -1 }
    }
```

Note: the function in the `update {}` lambda may be executed multiple times so it must NOT have side effects.

Comment: Will that still be thread-safe?

Comment: @Vahid yes is safe to call concurrently